# Dotnet core pubished site not working on IIS 10

Tags: .net-core, iis-10

I've an application developed on DOTNET Core 2.1. This app works fine in development environement i.e. on visual studio, all URLs are getting browsed.

But it's published copy is not working on IIS(version 10). On browsing, default URL gets hit and view gets displayed. But on browsing any other URL available in project displays Http 404 error.
*Configuration Details*
On IIS I could see the AspNetCoreModuelV2 is available.
[image: Handle Mapping]

Content of My Web.Config file are

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*"    resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication3.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use FRT to dig further, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis For certain kind of web applications, like Angular, you need a few URL Rewrite rules, but you didn't reveal what you are using in the question.

Comment: You also should tell us which kind of asp.net core application you have used now. MVC, Angular or else. Besides, you should also tell us how you hosted your web application in the IIS. Directly create a new IIS web application or into a nested web application.